# Using AWS CLI with MobaXterm on Windows

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli, mobaxterm

I am a newbie to both AWS and MobaXterm. I am trying to use MobaXterm to manage AWS instances because it comes with bash.

I am following the commands as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html.

When I run the following command `$ sudo ./aws/install`, I get the following error:

> Unable to start 'install': There is no application associated with the
> given file name extension.

I did run chmod 777 to ensure that I am able to read/write/execute. Please see attached image.

I do know that I can use Windows CLI installer in command line. However, doing SSH to EC2 is a nightmare in Windows with all certificates. With MobaXterm (because of bash), it is very easy. So, my preference is to use MobaXterm instead of Windows command prompt.

Moreover, I don't want to directly install Ubuntu. Hence, I am looking for some guidance here. I'd appreciate any help.

I am hoping that I am not missing any package. Thanks for any help.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

In order for AWS cli to run on MobaXterm, you will need to run the following commands in MobaXterm:

1. MobApt install python2-pip
2. pip2 install awscli

It will take some time for MobaXterm to complete steps 1 and 2. Also, AWS cli runs super slow in MobaXterm. You are better off using cmd.

This is the site that helped me ran AWS cli on MobaXterm.
https://majornetwork.net/2017/07/installing-aws-cli-on-cygwin/